# Uploading or just archiving an app for a client

Tags: ios, app-store, ios-provisioning

I know this has been talked before, but I don't know if this changes with recent changes in the App Store.

I'm a freelance developer, and as such I develop apps for many different clients, each of which have their own Apple Developer accounts to sell their apps on the App Store.

I know I can't upload the app myself for my client (not without their private key) I'm looking for an "easy" way to get the app on the App Store with as less effort as possible for the client side.

Options I can think of:

- Getting the private key and credentials for the client and upload it for them. But I would like to avoid that.
- Client adds me as a member of their iOS team, set me as a developer for the app and I download the provisioning profiles and somehow send them a file they can resign and upload to the store.
- I upload the app to my account and then use the new [transfer funcionality](http://www.macrumors.com/2013/06/10/apple-updates-itunes-connect-with-app-transfer-functionality/) to put it under the client name.

I don't know, there HAS to be a way, hasn't it?

**EDIT:**
I seem to have found a way, its described in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19321669/942420).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry I didn't accept any of the answers yet, but I've been trying some stuff and I think I found a way, a little strange and probably not optimal, but it could work and I would like to share it with you to see if you think it's ok.

First: I'm a developer with **my own Apple ID** and developer certificate. I have my own apps on the app store.

Second: I also make **client work** and then I want to upload and manage the apps I do for them, to a certain extent.

Third: My client has to have **their own developer account** and it has to be a **company** account, which will allow them to manage teams.

This is what I think that works:

1. I ask my client to add me to their iOS Developer Team as an "**admin**". This is done through the member center. This allows me to create distribution certificates and distribution provisioning profiles, as stated in [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/index.php).
2. After I accept the invitation (can't remember if I really have to) I log into the member center. It will ask me to **select the team** I want to use for my session (my own team or one of my clients'). I choose my client's team.
3. I go to Certificates and create a **new Certificate for Production**->App Store and Ad Hoc (I think there's a max of two per account, so if there are already two of them this option will be grayed out)
4. I have to upload a **CSR file** generated from my computer's keychain, following on screen instructions, and then my certificate is ready to download and use.
5. While I'm on member center I generate my **AppID** and then go to Provisioning Profiles and generate a new **Distribution Profile** for the App Store with my AppID and for the certificate just created.

That's it for member center, now I can download the distribution profile for the app I'm am developing for my client. Or let XCode 5 manage it.

Then I want to upload the app to the store and manage it with iTunes Connect with my own account.

1. I ask the client to iTunes Connect -> Manage Users -> iTunes Connect User and add me with a **Technical role**. This allows me to manage apps, but I wont see anything about banks, contracts, payments...
2. The problem with point 1 here is I already have an iTunes Connect account for myself with my email address and you can't have two iTunes Connect accounts linked to one email address. I could use a different address, but as I'm using gmail, I just use an [alias](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en). I give them the address: **myemail+clientname@gmail.com**
3. Once invited, I receive an activation mail and then I can log into iTunes Connect with that address and create apps and set them ready to upload.
4. Then I just have to go to Xcode, select my client's code **signing identity** (which is the certificate I created), the apps **distribution provisioning profile** (I created earlier too), archive, validate and submit to the app store with **my alias for this client**.

I've just tested it and it works.

It's not yet an optimal solution because when logging into iTunes Connect I can see every other app my client has and I could, potentially, delete something. But still, I think is a pretty good one for clients with no knowledge of XCode (or no interest in doing all this) but also wanting to keep their credentials and private keys secret.

Comment: By the way, I also could stop after the member center part. Generate and ipa and send it to my client for them to upload with Application Loader (no XCode required). Then I wouldn't need the iTunes Connect account, but they'd have to configure the app themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach should vary for the technical ability for your clients. Having them export a "Developer Profile" of all the certificates would allow you to manage the process.

If they are comfortable downloading XCode and submitting the app then you can just become a member of the team or just send them the Xcode project with instructions to change the code signing in build settings.

Without a private key, you can't submit and sign the app.

**Exporting a Developer Profile in Xcode 5**

- In the Xcode Preferences window, click Accounts.
- Click the Action button (to the right of the minus button) in the lower-left corner.
- Select Export Accounts from the pop-up menu.

You will then be allowed to password protect the .developerprofile

Comment: Don't want to send them the project, that could lead to errors with xcode versions or libraries and so. To export the "developer profile" they have to do it with keychain access or now with Xcode 5, don't they? Is there a way to do it through the provisioning portal?

Comment: Yes, I know that, that's what I was asking. But if they don't have XCode? Isn't there a way to do it through the provisioning portal?

Comment: No there is not because the provisioning portal does not store the private key

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer, see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend asking the client to add you to his dev center team as well as a iTunes Connect user , you can then take over the uploading and make the app uploading part smooth.

If the client has a Mac and already knows how to upload apps.. you could just send xcode archive for him/her to upload.. this though might make the process slower due to communication/other things.

Transferring ownership isnt an optimal solution since after transferring, next updates would require client keychain and provisioning profile which will bring you back to step one.

Comment: You are right about transferring ownership. But, I don't understand what you say about my client adding me to his dev center team and iTunes Connect. Only the team agent can upload apps, and there is only one team agent, isn't it?

Comment: About the xcode archive, you mean the *.xcarchive file? Can I sign that with my developer profile, being part of their team, and have them select the provisioning profile themselves? (by opening the file in xcode)

Comment: for 1st , dev center and iTunes connect are seperate , iTunes connect user can upload and the dev center team member can handle the provisioning , for 2nd comment , you can sign using client app store profile and send the xarchive , then client can enter his itunes connect id to upload build in his xcode (you just wont be doing the itunes connect part in this case)

Comment: So what you are saying is I need their profile either way. I can't create the archive with my profile even if I'm part of their team as a member.

Comment: yes.. provisioning profile requires bundle id and i dont think you and client can have same bundle id used..

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer, see if it makes sense.